# apple pay - sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I just start to work with applepay,
I'm trying to develop in local machine , I defined a merchantid, identifier, and all marked as verified in my apple developer account

I'm using ngrok to be able to get to my machine from outside- I'm able to get to this file
.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

But when I am using this request :
curl https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/paymentSession -d 'const options= {
url: "paymentSession url ",
cert: "./applepay.cer",
key: "./merchantid.cer",
method: 'post',
body:{
merchantIdentifier: "merchant.myDomin.com",
displayName: "myDomin",
initiative: "web",
initiativeContext: "myDomin.myDomin.com"
},
json: true,
}'
I get the error :
EPROTO 4517103040:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3readbytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1494:SSL alert number 40

What am I doing wrong ?
(The apple pay pop is showing during the flow , and I fail in session.onvalidatemerchant event

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"merchantIdentifier":"merchant.***.xxxxx","displayName":"Test 
Pay","initiative":"web","initiativeContext":"***-***-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx"}' --cert cert.pem:cert.pem 
'https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession'
```

This is the valid curl request which I used to get session from the apple pay servers.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/setting_up_your_server

please check whether all the server requirements are filled or not. As well as in node.js you need to specify the minimum TLS version. (In my case, I did it with the request).

refer my code: [Unable to get any response from the apple pay - This resource came from a local override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470730/unable-to-get-any-response-from-the-apple-pay-this-resource-came-from-a-local/67579481#67579481)

If you have filled all the server requirements issue should be with your merchant Identity Certificate.

discussion - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679789?login=true&page=1#674694022