# Unable to get any response from the apple pay - This resource came from a local override

Tags: ios, applepay, applepayjs, payment-request-api

I am integrating the apple pay and following the payment request API!
According to the documentation
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/requesting_an_apple_pay_payment_session)

**cert: merchIdentityCert and key: merchIdentityCert both are the same. I append my merchantIdentityCertificate.pem to both cert and key.**

**But, Unable to get any response from the apple pay servers. After my request it is throwing an error and safari is displaying a message as “This resource came from a local override”**

Code:

```
const merchIdentityCert = fs.readFileSync("./merchIdentityCert.pem")
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  cert: merchIdentityCert,
  key: merchIdentityCert,
  maxVersion: "TLSv1.2",
  minVersion: "TLSv1.2"
})
const post = (url, body) => {
logger.info({ message: "apple pay START", url, body })
fetch(url, {
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  method: "POST",
  agent: httpsAgent
}).then(resp => {
logger.info({ message: "apple pay SUCCESS", resp })
return resp
}).catch((error) => {
logger.info({ message: "apple pay ERROR", error })
return error
})
}
```

Logs:

*message: "apple pay START", url:
"https://-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession", body: {"merchantIdentifier":"***.*.****","displayName":"Test
Pay","initiative":"web","initiativeContext":"*-*-**.****."}

message: "apple pay ERROR", error: {}*

I am using a node-fetch library. My web app and node app deployed in AWS servers. I have fulfilled server setup and environment setup requirements with certificates.
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/setting_up_your_server]

**Does anyone have an idea about this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to resolve the {"size":0,"timeout":0} issue and it is related to node fetch library. I fixed it from my code level.
([Node-fetch problems with POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841983/node-fetch-problems-with-post-requests), https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Apart from that, I used the below request to debug using the remote server, and It was giving the session object to me.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"merchantIdentifier":"merchant.***.xxxxx","displayName":"TestPay","initiative":"web","initiativeContext":"***-***-xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx"}' --cert cert.pem:cert.pem 'https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession'
```

my code:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import fs from "fs"
import { promiseReject } from "../utils/misc"
import { Logger } from "../services/Logger"
import https from "https"
const logger = new Logger("Apple Pay Client")
const checkStatusAndGetJSON = (fetchResponse) =>
    fetchResponse.ok
        ? fetchResponse.json()
        : fetchResponse.json().then(promiseReject)
const merchIdentityCert = fs.readFileSync("./merchIdentityCert.pem")
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    cert: merchIdentityCert,
    key: merchIdentityCert,
    maxVersion: "TLSv1.2",
    minVersion: "TLSv1.2"
})
const basicHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "lang": "en",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
const post = (url, body) => {
    const start = Date.now()
    return fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: basicHeaders,
        method: "POST",
        agent: httpsAgent
    }).then(resp => {
        const duration = Date.now() - start
        logger.debug(`apple pay call took ${duration} millis.`, { endpoint: url, method: "POST", duration })
        return resp
    }).then(checkStatusAndGetJSON)
}
/** Apple Pay */
export const performValidation = (url, body) => post(url, body)
```

Comment: more details: [link] (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679789?login=true&page=1#674694022)

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the private key of my merchIdentityCert and I fixed it. After installing the .cer file, expand it from the Keychain Access, and export 2 items as .p12 and convert it to .pem using OpenSSL. Now, I have a PEM file that contains both assets. Then I continued my process and didn’t get the below error in this time which I mentioned in the above post.

message: "apple pay ERROR", error: {}

But, After the request, I am getting below log,

**message: "apple pay SUCCESS", resp: {"size":0,"timeout":0}**

As well, In the Inspect Element → Network → (click on my request) → Preview

Top of the response Preview, It is displaying a message as “Reveal | This resource came from a local override”

**Does anyone have an idea?**
*I am getting {"size":0,"timeout":0} from apple pay servers*